# Handling Status Dilemma

Tags: php, node.js, database, api, web-services

There is a recurring problem regarding status fields and similar predefined set of values.

Let's take an example of an ordering system with an order entity which has a status that could be New, In Progress, Paid, etc.

### The problem:

The Status of an order need to be

- stored (in database)
- processed (in backend)
- communicated (to frontend in web service API)

How to do these three activities while keeping:

- Preserve the meaning of the status.
- efficient storage.

Here are some example implementations with their pros and cons:

### 1- Status Table

- The database will contain a status table with id, name
- Order table references the id of the status.

  ```
  CREATE TABLE `status` (
    `id` INT NOT NULL,
    `name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`));

  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `order` (
    `id` INT NOT NULL AUTOINCREMENT,
    `status_id` INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX `order_status_idx` (`status` ASC),
    CONSTRAINT `order_status_id`
      FOREIGN KEY (`status_id`)
      REFERENCES `status` (`id`)
      ON DELETE NO ACTION
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION);
  ```
- The backend code has an enum that gives these predefined integers a meaning in the code

  ```
  enum Status {
      PAID = 7;
  };

  // While processing as action ...
  order.status = Status::PAID;
  ```
- The web service API will return the status number

  ```
  order: { id: 1, status_id: 7 }
  ```
- The frontend code has a similar enum that gives these predefined integers a meaning in the code. (like the backend code)
- **Pros:**

  - The database is well defined and normalized
- **Cons:**

  - The mapping between the status number and meaning is done in three places which gives space for human errors and inconsistency in defining the meaning of a specific status number.
  - The returned data from the API is not descriptive because `status_id: 7` does not deliver a concrete meaning because it does not include the meaning of the `status_id: 7`

### 2- Status ENUM

- In database, the order table will contain a status columns with type ENUM containing the predefined statuses.

  ```
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `order` (
    `id` INT NOT NULL AUTOINCREMENT,
    `status` ENUM('PAID') NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`));
  ```
- The backend code has constant values as code artifacts for the predefined status

  ```
  enum Status {
      PAID = 'PAID'
  };
  ```

  OR

  ```
  class Status {
  public:
      static const string PAID = PAID;
  };
  ```

  To Be used as follwoing

  ```
  // While processing as action ...
  order.status = Status::PAID;
  ```
- The web service API will return the status constant

  ```
  order: { id: 1, status: 'PAID' }
  ```
- The frontend code will have a similar construct for predefined status constants. (like the backend code)
- **Pros:**

  - The database is well defined and normalized
  - The returned data from the API is descriptive and deliver the required meaning.
  - The status constants used already contain their meaning which reduces the chances of errors.
- **Cons:**

  - Using an ENUM type for a column in database has its limitations. Adding a new status constant to that enum later using an ALTER command is expensive specially for huge tables like `order` table.

### 3- My proposed solution:

- The database will contain a status table with one field called `key` with type string which is the primary key of this table.

  ```
  CREATE TABLE `status` (
    `key` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`key`));
  ```
- The order table will contain a field called `status` with type string which references the `key` field of the `status` table.

  ```
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `order` (
    `id` INT NOT NULL AUTOINCREMENT,
    `status` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX `order_status_idx` (`status` ASC),
    CONSTRAINT `order_status`
      FOREIGN KEY (`status`)
      REFERENCES `status` (`key`)
      ON DELETE NO ACTION
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION);
  ```
- The backend code has constant values as code artifacts for the predefined status

  ```
  enum Status {
      PAID = 'PAID'
  };
  ```

  OR

  ```
  class Status {
  public:
      static const string PAID = PAID;
  };
  ```

  To Be used as follwoing

  ```
  // While processing as action ...
  order.status = Status::PAID;
  ```
- The web service API will return the status constant

  ```
  order: { id: 1, status: 'PAID' }
  ```
- The frontend code will have a similar construct for predefined status constants. (like the backend code)
- **Pros:**

  - The database is well defined and normalized
  - The returned data from the API is descriptive and deliver the required meaning.
  - The status constants used already contain their meaning which reduces the chances of errors.
  - Adding a new status constant is simple with INSERT command in the status table.
- **Cons:**

  - ???

### I'd like to know if this is a feasible solution or there is a better solution for this recurring problem.

#### Please include reasons why the proposed solution is bad and why your better solution is better

Thank you.

Comment: With a varchar primary key (entropy) you can use type enum
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/enum.html
, the database becomes not well normalized since you use a logical key as FK., in my opinion, keep your database  with lookup table as status, and don't have to expose the database structure to your API as it endpoint for front-end you can follow any pattern and make the transformation to acceptable data type or structure - MVVM for example and relay on modelview to handle it

Comment: Please add an answer including: 1) reasons why the proposed solution is bad. 2) Why your better solution is better. Take the following into consideration: 1) Completeness. 2) Preventive engineering. 3) Performance. 4) Consistency at all levels. 5) any other quality attributes you believe they are related to the case

Comment: Every working solution is a solution, 1) the proposed solution is not going normalization rules (n1st, n2nd), 2) mine(which you use in your question the 1st one)  keep database normalized with (fk),  let the RestAPI return `{status:'PAID'}` not to assume  the API should expose the database structure  that is simply without completed, and in code just return the string value for status that matches the relation the clear attribute for me that the performance will defect since need to load the related row from status table

Comment: I don't see any plus for creating a one-column table and using it as a foreign key for a status field. This is exactly what an enum does. So considering 2 and 3 are the same, 3 is better because of simplicity.

For the rest: there is a lot of convention needed to communicate status. That's okay, just write down the different status values in the docs somewhere. It is part of the backend API that the frontend should use.

Comment: @JelmerJellema We may agree it the end that there is no magic (automatic) way to handle status and it needs to be part of the docs for backend API. But for 2 and 3 comparison: The foreign key puts a constraint on the field. As far as I know, The enum field is expensive to alter while adding a record in the status table is cheap.

Comment: @MeenaAlfons Sure, the constraint helps and changing the possible values of an enum in a large table can cause troubles with locking and processing time. But then again: it makes the table self contained and more readable. I care more for people having it easy than I do for computers having to work hard ;-)

Answer (score 1):

This my approach for this problem:

1. I add a column `status` with type `string` in the `orders` table.
2. Define the constant of all your statuses in your class so you can reference them easily.
3. Make a validation rule on creation of order that the status value is in the only allowed ones you defines earlier.

This makes adding a new status very easily by just editing your code base, and the retrieved value for the status is still a string (descriptive).

I hope this answer your question.

Comment: Good but the DB will allow any string in `status` and the DB does not have neither information nor constraint about the possible values of this field. What do you think about that?

Comment: I don't think that should be a big deal, as you shouldn't have any interaction (especially creating records) with your database layer directly; there should always be a layer of application logic to either retrieve, create, update or delete from your database.

Comment: The proposed solution already includes yours with two additional pros: 1) The database includes information about the available states which makes the DB complete. 2) The domain of the `status` field is restricted to the accepted values for `status`.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest this:

1. Store in DB as status(unsigned tinyint, char(5)).
2. Id must be powers of 2: 1,2,4,8,...
3. At backend code const name must be humanized, but value -- int: `const PAID = 2`
4. At backend you should not use consts directly, but use status class object, which will contain some methods like `value` and `name`.
5. This class's test will check that all of it's values are in DB and all DB's values are covered by class.

> space for human errors

Tests invented to avoid human errors.

Statuses are usually not so complex and has not so many values to mess with them.

Enum is evil. http://komlenic.com/244/8-reasons-why-mysqls-enum-data-type-is-evil/

Regarding your proposal:

> The database is well defined and normalized

No. It's denormalized.

> The returned data from the API is descriptive and deliver the required meaning.

You always can use wrapper, that goes into status table to get human name.

> The status constants used already contain their meaning which reduces the chances of errors.

Const name are for humans and values are for Benders.

> Adding a new status constant is simple with INSERT command in the status table.

Same in 1st and my solution.